# Jquery only working with source code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a html file, in which I am dynamically loading data using AJAX and PHP.
They are no big deal, as they work fine, but I still have got a Problem.
I have (for showing purposes) created two divs, which are showing literally the same in DOM, but one is also shown in the source code. (The one div is loaded dynamically, in the other one I've loaded the results already from the start.)
Like this:

```html
<div>
    <ul> 
        <!-- Here is some data which is shown correct -- >
        <!-- (too much to REALLY put it in here -->
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="result">
    <!-- This should show the exact same output, but well isn't... -->
</div>
```

I've already looked after some similar things, but nothing helped me solve my Problem, as my request for the "result" is

```js
function kommissionsakte(o, s) {
    $("#result").empty();
    var xmlHttp = {};
    xmlHttp = ajaxHandler(xmlHttp);

    // Wenn das Objekt erfolgreich erzeugt wurde            
    var url = "ajax/getKommissionsakten.php";

    suchwert = escape($("#suchwert").val());
    var params = "o=" + o + "&s=" + s + "&suchwert=" + suchwert;

    if (suchwert != '') {
        $("#suchwert").css("border-color", "#31ae1c");

        loading();
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

        //Headerinformationen für den POST Request
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                $("#result").html(xmlHttp.responseText);
                closeLoading();
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.send(params);
    } else {
        $("#suchwert").focus();
        $("#suchwert").css("border-color", "#b20e10");
    }
}
```

My idea was to somehow get `#result` not as div id but INTO the div, but I am bad, so I have no idea how.

EDIT: Okay Long Explanation:

I try to load a Filetree using jquery into a page, that is already loaded. The Code creating the tree is working fine, it just doesn't work when I try to load it into this page. I've read that jquery is using DOM and not source code, so it should work properly, but it doesn't.

I can search for a keyword in a search function and the file tree is showing them. In the manually created div, is the Code, which creates the tree and jquery is manipulating it properly, if I now load that exact same Code into the other div, jquery isn't manipulating it.

Also i Am REALLY (like REALLY REALLY bad at JS) so it would be very, very nice to have a long Explanation in the answer.

EDIT2:
Requested PHP File Code:

```html
<?php
include '../include/ebene.inc.php';
include $ebene.'include/error_reporting.inc.php';
include $ebene.'include/db.inc.php';
include $ebene.'include/getSprache.inc.php';
include $ebene.'include/funktionen-standard.inc.php';
include $ebene.'include/funktionen-individuell.inc.php';
include $ebene.'include/konfig.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['suchwert'])){
$suchwert =($_POST['suchwert']);
$php_file_tree = '';
$first_call = true; 
$neue_seite = false;

 if($suchwert != ''){
  $parentsql = "SELECT TOP 10 KOM_Nummer from dbo.V_Kommisions_Akte_EN WHERE KOM_Nummer LIKE '%$suchwert%' group by KOM_Nummer";
  $parameter = array();
  $optionen =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
  $parent = sqlsrv_query($dbD3, $parentsql, $parameter, $optionen);
  $parentanzahl = sqlsrv_num_rows($parent); 
  if($parentanzahl != 0){
  $neue_seite = true;
  
    
   if($anzahl >= 200){
   
    echo '<br /><div align="center">'.$var['verfeinern'].'</div>';
   
   }else{
   
    echo '<br /><div align="center">'.$var['anzahl_ergebnisse'].': '.$parentanzahl.'</div>';
    
   }
  $php_file_tree .= "<ul";
  if($first_call) {$php_file_tree .= " class=\"php-file-tree\""; $first_call = false;}
  $php_file_tree .= ">";
  
  
   while($komnr = sqlsrv_fetch_array($parent, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   
    $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"pft-directory\"><a href=\"#\">" . htmlspecialchars($komnr['KOM_Nummer']) . "</a><ul>";
    $komnrregister = $komnr['KOM_Nummer'];
     
    $subsql = "SELECT TOP 10 KOM_Nummer, Register from dbo.V_Kommisions_Akte_EN where KOM_Nummer = '$komnrregister' group by KOM_Nummer, Register";
    $parameter = array();
    $optionen =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $sub = sqlsrv_query($dbD3, $subsql, $parameter, $optionen);
    $subanzahl = sqlsrv_num_rows($sub); 
    
    while($register = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sub, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    
    
     $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"pft-directory\"><a href=\"#\">" . htmlspecialchars($register['Register']) . "</a><ul>";
     $registerdokuid = $register['Register'];
     
    $slavesql = "SELECT TOP 10 KOM_Nummer, Register, doku_id from dbo.V_Kommisions_Akte_EN where Register = '$registerdokuid' AND KOM_Nummer = '$komnrregister' group by KOM_Nummer, Register, doku_id";
    $parameter = array();
    $optionen =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $slave = sqlsrv_query($dbD3, $slavesql, $parameter, $optionen);
    $slaveanzahl = sqlsrv_num_rows($slave); 
    
     while($doku = sqlsrv_fetch_array($slave, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     
      $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"pft-file ext-xls\"><a href=\"#\">" . htmlspecialchars($doku['doku_id']) . "</a></li>";
      
     }
    $php_file_tree .= '</ul></li>'; 
    } 
    $php_file_tree .= '</ul>';
   }
  $php_file_tree .= '</ul>';
  }
 
  echo $php_file_tree;

 //return ($php_file_tree);
 
 
 
 }


}    
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What are you trying to do? If the content of both divs is supposed to be the same, why bother with an AJAX request when you can just `clone()` the original? What is the value of `xmlHttp.responseText`? What URL are you calling? You've not described the problem and there's not nearly enough information here to diagnose whatever that problem might be.

Comment: why don't you use $.ajax({}) as you are using jquery?

Comment: Yea... please reword your question and explain a little more

Comment: Yes the Content of both divs are correct, because i've inserted ONE of MANY different results into one, to Show my Problem properly, also I just editted it, because i saw the Problem right now.

Comment: As suggested, You jquery ajax/post/get methods.. will make your life easier..

Comment: Did you ever wonder if the problem was not located in the php file that creates the file tree?^^ Please show your "called"  php file code...

Comment: Thats why I manually created the first div, in which I put the Output of the PHP, and it works just fine (PS. I am REALLY bad at JavaScript and can't get along with it at all, the JS part is written by a coworker, who is ill atm)

Comment: The code, as posted should work fine. I have a nagging feeling that `ajax/getKommissionsakten.php` is not returning correct data. Try loading that page manually from your web browser's address bar and see if the returned html isn't accidentally escaped or quoted in some way

Comment: By "that page" I mean `ajax/getKommissionsakten.php`

Comment: I've done that too, and got a correct Output from which I've filled the first div with...

Comment: bring the problem to its simpliest state and write it down there : jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wga11eex/14/ start there... this simple test is working...

Comment: thanks, i think I will get along now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer needs some edits, but you should try something like this :

```
function getMyPage(pageUrl,someData,callback){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : pageUrl,
        data : {'postName':someData},
        error : function(response){
            console.log("something wrong "+response+" - "+response.responseText+" - "+JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        success : function(response){
            callback(response);
        }
    });
})
```

Then somewhere in your code :

```
$("body").on("click","#yourButton",getMyPage('http://anything','your data',function(back){
    $("#yourDiv").html(back);
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using XMLHttpRequest, it's just a little more verbose than the jQuery alternative. What OP has already works in this regard.

Comment: he's using Jquery, I don't mean that there's something wrong using his request, but that'll just make things shorter and clear...